# Javascript returns undefined in html tags but shows result in developer console

Tags: javascript, html, matrix, console, spiral

I have a problem rendering the output of this code on textarea in html page, but it runs and shows the correct output on the console. Below is the html and javascript codes.. Thanks

```
<body>
<div class="input">
    <div class="numb">
        <form class="form-group" name="number" id="number">
            <input id="textbox" type="text" name="textbox" placeholder="Enter N">
            <button type="button" name="submit" id="button" onclick="final()">Get Matrix</button>
        </form>

    </div>
    <div class="result">
        <textarea id="spiral" name="spiral" placeholder="matrix"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
function createMatrix(size) {
const array = [];
for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    array.push(new Array(size));
}
return array;}

function spiral(input) {
const output = createMatrix(input);
let n = 1;
let a = 0;
let b = input;
let direction = 0; // 0 = right, 1 = down, 2 = left, 3 = up
let directionFlip = true;
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
while (n <= (input * input)) {
    output[x][y] = n;
    n++;
    a++;
    if (a >= b) {
        a = 0;
        if (direction === 0 || direction === 2 && directionFlip) {
            b--;
        }
        directionFlip = !directionFlip;
        direction = (direction + 1) % 4;
    }

    switch(direction) {
        case 0:
            x++;
            break;
        case 1:
            y++;
            break;
        case 2:
            x--;
            break;
        case 3:
            y--;
            break;
    }
}
return output;}
```

A print function to define the matrix order of this form spirally
1 2 3
8 9 4
7 6 5

```
function print(input, paddingChar) {
const longest = (input.length * input.length).toString().length;
const padding = paddingChar.repeat(longest);
for (let y = 0; y < input.length; y++) {
    let line = "";
    for (let x = 0; x < input.length; x++) {
        line += (padding + input[x][y]).slice(-longest) + " ";
    }
    console.log(line.toString());
}}
```

and a function to call it in the html page and return the square matrix

```
function final() {
input = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
let text = print(spiral(input), " ");
document.getElementById("spiral").innerHTML = text}
```

so if i input n from page, i get the matrix of n shown in developer console but not in the html page node

Comment: Your `print` function doesn't return anything, and `let text = print(spiral(input), " ");` therefore doesn't put the output into `text`.

Answer (score 1):

you are not returning anything from print function; here is updated fiddle to concatenate the text and return the text in matrix

https://jsfiddle.net/gowrimr/mjvn3fru/7/

```
`let text = ''
```

after console in print function add:

```
text = text+line.toString()+'\n'
```

finally do a `return text`

Comment: Thanks guys...i got over it by changing theconsole.log(line.toString());

Answer (score 0):

Your `print` function doe not return a value, therefore `text` is `undefined`. Add something like `return line.toString();` at the end of your `print` function.